# Skip the line of execution in shell script if the line take more time to execute

Tags: shell, scripting, logic, sh, websphere-8

I have a shell script which will stop the JVM in IBM WebSphere

As like below

```
//Some code 
sh /application/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/stopServer.sh JMS-Server -username admin -password ...... 
echo "Stop xyzServer JVM" 
//Some code
```

My problem is , when sometimes it take lot of time to stop the server,hence, script will keep on run and will never end

I need a solution to skip this line of execution, if this code waits for the finish of JVM stop, if JVM is not stopped after certain time, execution should move on to the next line

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timeout command:

```
//Some code 
timeout 180 sh /application/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/stopServer.sh JMS-Server -username admin -password ...... && echo "Stopped xyzServer JVM" || echo "xyzServer JVM stop, timeout" 
//Some code
```

Run the stopServer.sh script and if it doesn't return an exit code in 180 seconds or the exit code is not 0, print "xyzServer JVM stop, timeout" else print "Stopped xyzServer JVM"

Comment: No worries. If this meets your objective, please take the time to accept the solution.

Comment: I have kept timeout 20 sh /application/......   i could see it correctly routing to else condition in case of issues in restart , but i cannot see it is wating for 20 seconds, instead it is immediately routing, is it because it is a background process?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to just append `&` at the end of your command, which will run it in a background shell.  Then, after you echo add a `sleep` command for however long you want to wait for stop command before continuing.  So overall, something like:

````
//Some code 
sh /application/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/stopServer.sh JMS-Server -username admin -password ...... &
echo "Stop xyzServer JVM" 
sleep 10m
//Some code```
````

Comment: If the thread runs in background and if stopserver execution hungs for long, will the execution still proceed to the next lines ? without effecting the entire execution of script? if that is the case, sleep is not required right?

Comment: It will continue immediately to the next line regardless of whether it hangs or not, whereas the question asked for " if JVM is not stopped after certain time", hence the sleep to satisfy that requirement.
With that said, the `timeout` command might be better if you want to kill the stop after a certain amount of time before moving on to the next line in your script (whereas the `&` and `wait` will not, unless you add a `kill` command, but at that point you should just use timeout....so it depends on what behavior you want).